# Customize YouTube Embed URL

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to modify the URL used to embed YouTube videos in an iframe (http://www.youtube.com/embed/_AJS0lgT-4a)? For example, adding the channel name.

My organization blocks YouTube so I need to create a rule on our proxy server to allow users to access our channel only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you load the videos directly from the user's channel, it'll look like this:
http://www.youtube.com/user/vsauce#p/u/4/CSf8i8bHIns
So you'd be on the user's channel homepage.

"/user/username" is your golden ticket, and #videoid will point to the video if you want to link directly to it.

Multiple other varibles are passed in the url that you can make exceptions for, most notably a playlist.  This string will appear somewhere in the url, generally tacked onto the end:

"&list=PLAYLISTIDHERE" ex. "&list=PLE126C843377DCE64"

One of those should do the trick as long as the admins are willing to play nice!

Best of luck!